# Node JS: How to open one route within another

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, web-frontend

I'm newbie in web front-end world. I have routes: `/product`, `/shop`. And for each route I have created controllers. The question is how can I open `/shop` route page from `/product` page. When I call `res.render('product');` it routes `http://localhost:3000/shop/products` instead of `http://localhost:3000/products`.

How can i solve this?

Comment: P.S.: opening /product from /shop

Comment: You can edit your question instead of the comment

Comment: What happens if you call `res.render('/product')`

Comment: Nothing, but request is coming to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirected to `http://localhost:3000/shop/products` because the current path before executing the request is: `http://localhost:3000/shop`
To go on `/products` directly, you can do the following

- You can use the `..` to invoke the parent in your filesystem (using a relative path)

```js
res.render('../products')
```

- Or simply using an absolute path

```js
res.render('/products')
```

Comment: `router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("test");
  res.render("../shop");
});`

Comment: With redirect: It writes "Not Found", <br />With render: Failed to lookup view "shop-product-render" in views directory "/Users/developer/Desktop/dilenta/views"
GET /product 500 3.356 ms - 1352

Comment: Are you sure, you have a file associated to the page `localhost:3000/products` ?

Comment: In my shop page  has products. And when I click on one of them with ajax I send request to my /product controller. In /product controller I wrote such code: res.render("shop-product-render"); In my views folder I have "shop-product-render.ejs also.

Comment: In your views folder you don't have products.ejs, do you?

Comment: no, I don't, but I have "shop-product-render.ejs", and I'm rendering it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160933/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-bakhrom-achilov).

Comment: @BakhromAchilov, don't forget to accept the answer and mark it as accepted if it helped you in anyway :)

Comment: edkeveked, thanx a lot, I found my miss! res.render('../products') works fine, but I understand it not correctly. I thought it directs to other route, but it only return html code as response. I sent request with ajax  to controller and as answer received html content. Silly me) Thanx a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> redirect

in your route Express redirect

Example:

```
app.get('/shop', function(req, res) {
 res.redirect('/products');
});
```